# How to stop canvas shifting when right click is pressed to show contextmenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I'm working on drawing map using shapes and add then to canvas, I've to show ContextMenu when MouseRightButtonDown, but there is shifting happened on canvas when I press the right button of mouse, So how can i stop this shifting?!

```
private void MainCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
            {
                Canvas c = sender as Canvas;
                ContextMenu contextMenu = c.ContextMenu;
                contextMenu.PlacementTarget = c;
                contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

```
<Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas"  Uid="parentCanvas"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDown="MainCanvas_MouseDown">

                <Canvas.ContextMenu >
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Name="CzechRepublic"
                        Header="Czech Republic"/>

                        <MenuItem Name="MiddleEurope"
                        Header="Middle Europe"/>

                        <MenuItem Name="Europe"
                        Header="Europe"/>

                        <MenuItem Name="WholeMap"
                        Header="Whole Map"
                        Click="WholeMap_Clicked"/>

                        <Separator />

                        <MenuItem Name="Settings"
                        Header="Settings"
                        Click="Settings_Clicked"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Canvas.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: I have copy-pasted all these codes to my WPF project but canvas is not shifting anywhere.Are you sure that the problem is in these codes?

Comment: yes, it's "jumping" to the top right, that's happend when i use zoom in on it and press right button